# Bootstrap modal with jQuery post

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a popup and form with validation, but for some reasonthe process.php is not being found I was told to reclairfy my question.

I am using the jQuery below to go to my processing file:

```
<div id="thanks" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Redeem Points</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <form class="form-horizontal" class="contact" name="commentform" method="post" action="<?php 
            bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/sendredeempoints.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="form-group">
            <h3>You may only redeem the maxium points of : <?php echo $maxpoints;?></h3>
            <input type="hidden" name="playerid" value="<?php echo $playerId;;?>" />
            <input type="number" valuemax="<?php echo $maxpoints;
                ?>" name="points" class="form-control" placeholder="How many points do you wish to redeem." />                  
            <label class="control-label col-md-4" for="Comments">Comments?</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <button title="" data-original-title="" type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-custom pull-right" id="send_btn">Send</button>
                <div style="top: -4px; left: 279px; display: block;" class="popover fade right in">
                    <div class="arrow"></div>
                    <h3 style="display: none;" class="popover-title"></h3>
                    <div class="popover-content">Thank You</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </form>
    </div><!-- End of Modal body -->
    </div><!-- End of Modal content -->
    </div><!-- End of Modal dialog -->
</div><!-- End of Modal --> 

<script>
$(function() {
    //twitter bootstrap script
    $("button#submit").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "process.php",
            data: $('form.contact').serialize(),
            success: function(msg){
                $("#thanks").html(msg)
                $("#form-content").modal('hide'); 
            },
            error: function(){
                alert("failure");
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Process.php

```
$playerid = $_POST['playerid']; // required        
$points = $_POST['points']; // required
$mymessage = $_POST['userMessage']; // required    
$email_from = 'email@example.com';
$email_subject = $_POST['mysubject'];
$email_to = $_POST['toEmail'];

$headers = 'From: ' . $email_from . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: ' . $email_from . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail( $email_to, $email_subject, $mymessage, $headers );
```

Comment: Look in your browser's console for error messages.

Comment: their is no errors that what im sayingits just simple getting a 404 not found

Comment: Please clarify your question. What is giving you a 404? process.php? Your question says the modal is not appearing.

Comment: @Milo i refclairfied it their at tht etop mate

Comment: You also may have better luck on the main StackOverflow site as this seems to have nothing to do with WordPress.

Answer (score 1):

If process.php is not found, your reference in the file is not correct. Make sure you reference to the correct path, for istance - if the file is in the rootdirectory of your site, add a slash in front of your code:

`url: "process.php",`

will be:

`url: "/process.php",`

If it is in the 'ajax' directory:

`url: "/ajax/process.php",`

Myself I usually provide a full path:

`url: "http://myserver.bla/process.php",`

Hope this helps